# LISP how to write this function without using LOOP

Tags: loops, functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

i wrote this function but i have been told i can't use the loop inside of it, i have no idea how to modify it in order to remove the loop.
any suggestion?

```
(defun function (P VariableValues)
(let* ((M (mono P))
        (VariableNames (variables P))
        (VariableDict (loop for x in VariableNames for y in VariableValues collect (cons x y)))
        (Valorizzati (mapcar (lambda (x) (applica-valori VariableDict x)) M))
    ) 
  (if Valorizzati
      (+ (car Valorizzati) (recursive-sum (cdr Valorizzati))) 
    0)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mapcar` for that:

```lisp
(mapcar #'cons '(a b c) '(1 2 3))
;; ==> ((a . 1) (b . 2) (c . 3))
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but i can't get it to work... any idea?

Comment: @user7337963 My code worked when I wrote the answer. It should work in all common lisp implementations. Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: if i just test the code you provided it works fine, when i implement it in my function it compiles with no errors but it gives me an error while testing the function

Comment: @user7337963 You should show the code you wrote. You must have written something wrong, but it's impossible for anyone to say what without seeing what you did.

Comment: this is how i implemented it

Comment: oops sorry pressed return by accident, here's the code 

    (VariableDict (mapcar #'cons (list variableNames) (list VariableValues)))

Comment: @user7337963 You shouldn't use `LIST` there. `variableNames` and `VariableValues` are already lists. You're just creating two single element lists (the single element being a list itself). You should also use the regular Lisp naming convention (`variable-names` instead of `VariableNames`).